# createStore(reducer) not working react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I've checked my code like 10 times, and I just cannot find the answer. I keep getting this error:

`Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string but got: undefined`

Here is my code:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import Provider from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import Header from './components/common/Header'
import Button from './components/common/Button'
import NumberLabel from './components/NumberLabel'
import reducers from './reducers/'

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <Provider store={createStore(reducer)}>
        {/* <View>
          <Header text='Counter'/>
          <NumberLabel />
          <Button text='Add One' onPress={this.incrementButtonPressed}/>
        </View>       */}
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import IncrementReducer from './IncrementReducer'

export default combineReducers({
  increment: IncrementReducer
})
```

**reducers/IncrementReducer.js**

```
export default (state, action) => {
  return []
}
```

Comment: `reducer` vs `reducers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try covering `Provider` in curly braces like below:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
```